# How to read `state` from Firebase Auth?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

Based on the [Firebase Auth documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider#setcustomparameters), I can set custom parameters using the `setCustomParameters` method on the `GoogleAuthProvider`

Looking at the [parameters accepted by Google's OAuth 2.0 authentication API](https://developers.google.com/identity/openid-connect/openid-connect#authenticationuriparameters), it indicates that the `state` parameter is "an opaque string that is round-tripped".

I am setting the value:

```
      googleAuthProvider.setCustomParameters({state:"myValue"});
```

And I can see that is gets added to the URL in the redirect when calling:

```
      await signInWithRedirect(auth, googleAuthProvider);
```

However, after authenticating, I do not see any value added to the redirect URL which returns the users to my page.

How can I read the value I passed in to "state"?

Answer (score 1):

The `.onAuthStateChanged` event will fire. This is what drives the state of your app/webapp. In terms of getting or reading the `state` custom parameter, it gets returned to your app via the redirect uri as `state=THE_STATE_PARAMETERS`.

> **Sets** the OAuth custom parameters to pass in a Google OAuth request for
> popup and redirect sign-in operations.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider#setcustomparameters

```
auth.onAuthStateChanged(function(user) { ...
```

Comment: In `onAuthStateChanged` I'm logging the `user`, but I don't see any property that holds the state value I passed in. Could you point me to the property?

Comment: Where you able to read this value ?