# Read custom parameters from Firebase Auth after sign in?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-oauth

This is similar to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74269693/how-to-read-state-from-firebase-auth)

```
const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider()
  provider.setCustomParameters({
    prompt: 'select_account',
    state: 'saveAction',
  })
  await signInWithRedirect(getAuth(), provider)
```

I am trying to understand is there a way to read any of the custom parameters inside my `getRedirectResult` after sign in is completed.

I need to pass some `state` from my app, like an action which user was doing, and its needs to completed after they are signed in.